# Returning iterator index on an array search

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

I would like to search for a specific number and have an iterator track the array element being tested. If the number is found I would like to return the index of the array where the number is found. Here's what I have so far:

```
    vector<int>::iterator iterator;
    find(vector.begin(),vector.end(), num);

    if(//the number is found in the search)
    {
       return //where the number is found
    }
```

I'm not quite sure how to sync the iterator up with the element of the array being tested. I would appreciate any help toward solving this problem if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "the adress of the array"? You want to return the memory adress of the element or simply its index?

Comment: Check out any example for `std::find()`. Then, dereferencing the iterator gives you a reference and taking the address of it gives you its address. Instead of using pointers unnecessarily, I'd rather use an iterator though. Also, consider using a reference, although that requires exceptions for the case that the element isn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
std::vector<int> v = {500, 600, 700};
auto it = std::find(v.begin(),v.end(), 600);
std::size_t pos = it - v.begin(); //found(iterator) - begin(iterator)

// of course first you should check if (it != v.end())
```